# Triple integral with dependent parameters

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

The form of my problem is as follows:

$\Psi=C\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(f(x,y)\times \left(\int_0^t g(x,t)dt\right)dxdy\right)$

I have already attempted numerical solutions using Matlab's `integrate3`, without success.
However `integrate3` is meant for problems of the form:

$\Psi=\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f f(x,y,z)dxdydz$

Similarly, attempts made with scipy's integration toolkit have also not borne fruit.

I have attempted to first calculate $\int_0^tg(x,t)$ at discrete $x$ values and then place it in $\Psi$ but for rather obvious reasons that does not work either.

Additionally, $g(x,t)$ cannot be factored in the form of $h(x)\times i(t)$, which might have allowed for a by parts solution which might be integrated symbolically (for x) and numerically for t.

Also $\int_0^t\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  g(x,t)$ has singularities at multiple points.

Is there a mathematica method to solve this?

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) I see mathematica seems to handle only region level integrations with integrate, so perhaps a linear solution in $t$ with a corresponding region integration over $x$ and $y$?

**UPDATE**

More specifically, I'm trying to reproduce the work of [Shen et. al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030101049287053C) so my equations are

```
shenPhiG[_g,_t]:= (1/(1+2(t/tc)))(1-Exp[(-2m*g/(1+2(t/tc)))])
shenU[_g]:=Exp[-(1+I*v)g]
NIntegrate[shenPhiG[g]*Exp[-I*(theta/tc)*NIntegrate[shenPhiG[g,t],{t,0,tf}]],{x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I've tried with tf as 5 or 10000 but I always get

`NIntegrate::inumr : The integrand shenPhiG[g,t] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1000}}.`

**UPDATE 2**

The equations being modeled are given in the paper (in spherical coordinates, hence the reduction of integrals) as:

$\Theta=\frac{\theta}{t_c}\int_0^t\frac{1}{1+\frac{2t^\prime}{t_c}}\left[1-\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{-2mg}{1+2\frac{t^\prime}{t_c}}\right)dt^\prime\right]$

and

$U_p=C\int_0^\infty \mathrm{exp}[-(1+\mathrm{i}V)g]\mathrm{exp}(-\mathrm{i}\Theta) dg$

With the approximation $\mathrm{exp}(-\mathrm{i}\Theta)\approx1-\mathrm{i}\Theta$

$U=C\int_0^{\infty}(1-\mathrm{i}\Theta)\mathrm{exp}[-(1+\mathrm{i}V)g]dg$

The form I've explained in the original question is obtained on converting to Cartesian coordinates.

Upon using

```
shenPhi[g_,t_]:=(1/(1+2(t/tc)))(1-Exp[(-2m*g/(1+2(t/tc)))])
```

and

```
shenU[g_]:=Exp[-(1+I*v)*g]NIntegrate[shenPhiG[g]*Exp[-I*(theta/tc)*
Integrate[shenPhiG[g,t], {t, 0, tf}]],
{g, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I get no output at all..

With

```
shenU[_g,t_]=Exp[-(1+I*v)*g]NIntegrate[shenPhiG[g]
*Exp[-I*NIntegrate[shenPhiG[g,t],{t,0,tf}]],{g,-Infinity,Infinity},{t,-Infinity,Infinity}
```

and

```
shenPhi[g_,t_]:=(theta/tc)(1/(1+2(t/tc)))(1-Exp[(-2m*g/(1+2(t/tc)))])
```

I get

NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand $\frac{1-\mathrm{exp}\left(-\frac{2g}{1+Times[<<2>>]} \right)}{1+\frac{t}{2542}}$ has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the refion with boundaries {{0,50000}}.

Throw::nocatch:
 Uncaught Throw[-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x\$373597]+Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y'[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x\$373597],NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation] returned to top level.

Comment: Do you have formulas for $f(x,y)$ and/or $g(x,t)$, or are you trying to solve for them? It seems like `NIntegrate` can probably make a decent attempt at this problem directly, but depending on the form of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,t)$, there may be better alternatives.

Comment: I have equations for $g(x,t)$ and $f(x,y)$ but I'm worried about the fact that $x$ appears in $g(x,t)$ from where $x$ needs to obtained for the RHS. ```NIntegrate``` requires a range and also seems to meant for problems like ```integrate3```

Comment: Mathematica can handle that form of problem.  But not all such problems, since some integrands are intractable. -- Is the integral over $t$ indefinite (upper limit $t$), or is that a typo?

Comment: No, it's meant to be $t$ (indefinite), in practice t is bound by an upper value, around 5000 (5s).

Comment: Is the `_g` in `shenPhiG[_g,...` a typo? If not, it's an error. You should have `g_` instead of `_g`.

Comment: Yup, that was fixed as in update 2 @MichaelE2

Answer (score 1):

You said you have definitions for $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,t)$ already, so the first step to trying to solve this problem with *Mathematica* would be to attempt the numerical integral directly after setting `tf` to the upper bound of the inner integral:

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y] NIntegrate[g[x,t], {t, 0, tf}],
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Due to the nested integrals, this may be a fairly slow calculation. It may be better to see if `Integrate` can find a reasonably closed form of the inner integral first:

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y] Evaluate[Integrate[g[x,t], {t, 0, tf}]],
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Though from the sounds of it, $g(x,t)$ probably won't allow that to be effective.

If `tf` is meant to be left as a variable, then numerical integration methods aren't going to be appropriate for solving this problem.

To provide further advice, examples of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,t)$ of equivalent complexity to the problem you're trying to solve would be necessary.

---

```
shenPhi[_g,_t]:=(1/(1+2(t/tc)))(1-Exp[(-2m*g/(1+2(t/tc)))])
```

Is actually a nonsensical declaration, since function definitions are divided into `name_pattern`, and thus the first and second arguments are actually nameless as it stands. Since this is going to be a numerical integration problem, ensure that `tc` and `m` have numerical values declared elsewhere and change that line to:

```
shenPhi[g_,t_]:=(1/(1+2(t/tc)))(1-Exp[(-2m*g/(1+2(t/tc)))])
```

Then based on your additional information, ensure that all constants also have numerical values and evaluate the integral:

```
shenU[g_]:=Exp[-(1+I*v)*g]NIntegrate[shenPhiG[g]*Exp[-I*(theta/tc)*
    Integrate[shenPhiG[g,t], {t, 0, tf}]],
    {g, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Clearly `x` needed to be changed to `g` to match the problem definition, but I'm not clear on which variable `y` is supposed to match -- so that will need to be changed as well.

It also appears from a preliminary inspection that the inner integral will need to be `Integrate` rather than `NIntegrate`, as the inner `NIntegrate` won't generally have a value for `g` to plug in.

Comment: Updated the question with more details...

Comment: @HaoZeke: Updated answer, hope this helps more, but I don't have access to that article at the moment and there's still some ambiguity in your code (`y` doesn't appear anywhere but the second integration variable, which value is it supposed to be?)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I'll update the question again... @eyorble